# How to identify which object is causing the problem in content deployment?

Tags: content-deployment, troubleshooting

Apart from the manifest.xml in exportedfiles.cab, Event Viewer and the ULS logs, is there any way to identify which object is causing the problem in content deployment?

Comment: What kind of problem are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You could try telling SharePoint to keep the temporary files. This can be done using stsadm:

STSADM -o editcontentdeploymentpath -pathname  -keeptemporaryfiles Never|Always|Failure

You can then look inside the various cab files and figure out what is going on (I didn't say it would be easy). This [blog article](http://techblog.ranjanbanerji.com/post/2008/04/07/SharePoint-Content-Deployment-Identifying-Object-Causing-Error.aspx) has some suggestions.

Stefan Gossner has a [good blog article on common content deployment problems](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/16/content-deployment-best-practices.aspx).